# Hide AngularJS jsonp requests from console/firebug

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, jsonp

I've seen some websites where the ajax requests are hidden from the console/firebug. Reading more about this, I saw some answers saying we need to use JSONP requests instead of regular AJAX calls.

However, when doing JSONP requests, like this:

```
$scope.debugFunction = function() {
    var url = '/request/jsonp.php?callback=JSON_CALLBACK'
    $http.jsonp(url)
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log('Success: ', data);
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log('Error: ', status);
    })
}
```

I'm still able to see the results on the console/firebug.

---

Is there a way to remove this from the console/firebug within the AngularJs enviroment?

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: @dfsq i was told to do it, so it would hide some information from the server, such as folder structure, etc..

Comment: You can't hide url's used by client. Any request made by users computer can be tracked.  Really not clear what you are expecting to accomplish